# Surfaceview android

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am new to Android. I'm trying to develop a game app using the surface view. The app runs properly but at the end when I exit it shows the null pointer exception on **onDraw()** method and the app gets crashed. Please help me out and thanks in advance.
Here is my code:-

```
public class Gameloopthread extends Thread {

    private Gameview view;
    static final long fps=30;
    boolean running;

    public Gameloopthread(Gameview view)
    {
        this.view=view;
    }
    // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
    // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
    public void setRunning(Boolean run)
    {
        running=true;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long tickps=3000/fps;
        long startTime=0;
        long sleepTime;

        while(running)
        {
            Canvas c=null;


            try{
                c=view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
                //Log.d("Canvas==>",""+c);
                synchronized(view.getHolder()){
                    view.onDraw(c);

                }
            }finally{
                if(c!=null){
                    view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime=tickps-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            try{
                if(sleepTime>0)
                {
                    sleep(sleepTime);
                }else{
                    sleep(30);
                }
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
        super.run();

    }
//  

}
```

Comment: onDraw() code and logcat output would be useful.

Comment: Yes, please post the logcat!

Comment: Search stackoverflow for this error. There are a couple of questions (including one of mine) that deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the lockCanvas call, the surface has probably been destroyed and you have passed a null canvas reference to view.onDraw(). There's some recommendations in the API on how to deal with surface state.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29)